# set scrollbar properties in firefox

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, scrollbar

I want to set the color of my scrollbar and for it to work in firefox as well.
I read that scrollbar's are not part of the w3c standard and therefore their customizing are not supported in firefox. Well, there must be some way to get it working. Does anyone how to do it?

Comment: There is no way to get it working. Firefox simply doesn't allow this. End of the story. You can only try what David Dorward suggested but I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: Yeah, Learn-To-Live-With-It is almost certainly the best solution. The flat `scrollbar-` colour properties don't really make any sense any more anyway, now most desktop environments are using complex themed shiny-scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of [faking your own scrollbar](http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20030324/026229.html) with JavaScript, it is impossible.

Comment: Faking a scrollbar in Flash works, too, although it's extremely poor form to do that. Better just to leave the scrollbars alone.

Comment: ohhh... I see, now that is really annoying